# How can I simulate user input in fish

Tags: linux, bash, fish

So I want to have a function that displays rsclock, then quits.
To exit rsclock, user presses 'Q'.
So I want to simulate this input in fish.
How can I?

Comment: FYI, The usual solution to dealing with programs that explicitly read from /dev/tty is to use a program like `expect` to control the interaction.

Comment: I knew nothing about scripting bash. I looked it up and found 'expect' and 'send' , then I tried. But not in a bash script, config file itself. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily you could do this with a pipe, but rsClock [explicitly opens](https://docs.rs/termion/1.1.1/src/termion/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/termion-1.1.1/src/tty.rs.html#33) `/dev/tty` instead of just reading from stdin, so it would be non-trivial with any shell.

One approach would be to send SIGINT after a delay:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

(sleep 1; killall -INT rsclock) &
rsclock
tput cnorm
```

but the path of least resistance is probably to just modify rsclock directly to support a timeout.

Comment: So I created a bash script that contains mentioned code and added `./script.sh` into my fish welcome function. seems to have worked. thanks.